# Swipe gesture from a nav controller to regular

Tags: swift, xcode

So I have an image here->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyfwF.png). I want to make a swipe gesture from the yellow view to the home view(the top one.) However one is a navigation controller and the other one is a regular. It doesn't work. Thank you in advance for for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code in swipe gesture action after `self.navigationController?.pushToViewController(..)`

```
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

And unhidden navigation bar in `viewWillAppear` method when you come back to yellow controller.